# Why were my gutters installed this way?

Tags: gutters

Getting new gutters soon because of water overflow and gutters that still get clogged even with guards. The new company showed pics of the current installation and it doesn't look right. From the pic can you tell why the old company installed the gutters this way?

There are a lot of these weird connections and openings in gutters.

[image: gutter corner, top]

Comment: The image was not visible, I have corrected it.  Maybe the question will reopen.  It's not in focus, but it looks like how many companies do it.  I am not a fan as it becomes hard or impossible to clean the gutters.  And they will fill up.  In this case, it looks like there is a side entry thus making it an ideal home for birds and vermin to nest and clog up the gutter.  I prefer just a simple wide netting for gutter guard.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that installation, except for the short section of gutter guard at the right angle turn.  I would remove that, or come with a batter of closing off the outside corner.  If you leave it open, you're not going to get much debris in that little opening, and it provides a way to snake a hose in under the gutter guards if needed.

Comment: A) What is it that you (or the new gutter company) think is wrong with the current installation? B) if you're replacing them anyway, what difference does it make how they're installed?

Comment: @FreeMan To answer B: [Chesterton's Fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G._K._Chesterton#Chesterton's_fence), or to put it another way "maybe the previous installer knew something the owner doesn't"

Comment: Your question isn't clear. I live under a canopy of mature oaks and ashes and your gutters look nearly identical to mine. What's your specific concern? I only open mine to clean them every few years and only because one section doesn't have enough slope. Otherwise, any small debris that drops through is washed away. The system works very well for deciduous leaves.

Answer (score 1):

The overflow issue is caused by a bad shingle job or crooked fascia boards. You've got 6 rows of drain holes at the beginning and end up with three rows further down. The roof looks to be crooked and the company just followed the crooked fascia or over-extended shingles when they installed the gutters. With an average rainfall, you will have overflow into the yard. The new company will need to correct this crookedness or at least shim out the gutters so the complete width of the gutters is past the rood deck.

Comment: Looks to me like the gutters were installed too low on the fascia, so that the water just skates right over the gutter guards.

Answer (score -1):

i'm just coming into this sir or ma'am but first off that's completely the wrong way that you join good or cover no matter the style or whether it's an inside corner outside corner or 30° bay corner. Secondly that's not the best choice of cover they could've chose or at least gave you enough information so that you would know that a better choice is out there forget a cover. Depending on the types of trees you have it's kind of how you go about which type of cover you need along with the material used for your roofing as well as the pitch of your roof. These things should be taken into account when deciding what type of gutter cover to go with. I am new to this website so I'm not sure how I would do it but I'd be glad to show you some covers that can be bought anywhere in the US. I'd be glad to show you pictures if I knew how to go along with that your corners should be cut in a clean cut 45°  angle and one should barely overlap the other. Whoever did the outside corner in the picture took a shortcut that's not what professionals do. Where the mouth will make you and break you in this business I've been in 20 years plus. Anyway I hope I can help with your situation with my input. Good luck sir or ma'am